# R, add seperate bewteen each word

Tags: r

I take column datas from a data set data, and hope to feed them into model variable list
    colnames(data)
    "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4"
The model variable list has the format below:
    c("col1", "col2","col3", "col4")
My challenge is the comma, how can I add them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste(colnames(data), collapse=',')